# How to get the id of span which is deep inside li when the li is clicked

Tags: jquery

```
 <li class="service">
                    <div class="name">>
                       <span class="price"></span>
                       Stock<span class="stock" id="ds"></span>
                    </div>
</li>
 <li class="service">
                    <div class="name">>
                       <span class="price"></span>
                       Stock<span class="stock" id="ju"></span>
                    </div>
</li>
 <li class="service">
                    <div class="name">>
                       <span class="price"></span>
                       Stock<span class="stock" id="zx"></span>
                    </div>
</li>
```

I want to get the id of the span which has the class name stock depending on the li clicked

```
$("li").click(function() {

        });
```

Comment: What about `this.querySelector('span.stock').id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the class selector with li so it would not add on all lis.

Try this:

```
$("li.service").click(function() {
      var spanid = $(this).find('span.stock').attr('id');

      alert(spanid);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `this` keyword within the `click` event handler to refer to the `li` which was clicked. From there you can use `find()` to retrieve the `span` you require before calling `prop()` to get the id. Try this:

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).find('.stock').prop('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="service">
    <div class="name">>
      <span class="price"></span> 
      Stock <span class="stock" id="ds"></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="service">
    <div class="name">>
      <span class="price"></span> 
      Stock <span class="stock" id="ju"></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="service">
    <div class="name">>
      <span class="price"></span>
      Stock <span class="stock" id="zx"></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to get the span with stock class. Use `attr` to get the attribute.

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).find('.stock').attr('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="service">
    <div class="name">
      <span class="price"></span> Stock
      <span class="stock" id="ds"></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="service">
    <div class="name">
      <span class="price"></span> Stock
      <span class="stock" id="ju"></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="service">
    <div class="name">
      <span class="price"></span> Stock
      <span class="stock" id="zx"></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```